# Why order of tables matter in self-join

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Here's my table and query as a fiddle. This produces the correct results, or the results that I'm looking for. In this query, m1 comes first, then m2, as you can see in the line "...microposts m1 inner join microposts m2..."

```
SELECT *
FROM microposts m1
INNER JOIN microposts m2
ON m1.ancestry = m2.id AND m2.user_id=1 AND m1.user_id=2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec0c88/3

Now if you switch m1 and m2 (i.e. "...microposts m2 inner join microposts m3...", the 'original post' is returned (the micropost who is the ancestor of the 'reply post').

```
select *
from microposts m2
inner join microposts m1
on m1.ancestry = m2.id and m2.user_id=1 and m1.user_id=2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec0c88/2

Everything is working correctly in my application, I'm just trying to understand self-joins a little better. Because the way I am conceptualizing them, I wouldn't have expected these results.

Thanks for introducing me to SQLFiddle. It's pretty cool.

Comment: Your second query has an extra `m2.user_id = 1` check. So they're not equivalent.

Comment: You've got different conditions in the two SQL statements (the user_id).

Comment: BTW, the `ON` clause should only contain conditions that relate the two tables. Single-table conditions should be in the `WHERE` clause (except in some cases of outer joins).

Comment: dangit! i made a mistake! i meant to type the types *as if* they were identical. i've made the change to include the m1.user_id query in the first statement. now i'd like to now why they produce different results.

Comment: Can you setup a self-contained test case on SQLFiddle that shows that the two statements are different?

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about SQLFiddle. Here's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's why I said "except in some cases of outer joins".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you used `SELECT *`. As a result, the column names from both `m1` and `m2` are the same. But only one of each pair of same-named columns is returned in the result set, and which one depends on the order that the aliases appear in the query.

I changed the query to give distinct aliases to the columns from each table, and now the results are the same when swapping the order:

```
SELECT m1.id AS id1, m1.content as content1, m1.ancestry AS ancestry1, m1.user_id as userid1,
       m2.id AS id2, m2.content as content2, m2.ancestry AS ancestry2, m2.user_id as userid2
FROM microposts m2
INNER JOIN microposts m1
ON m1.ancestry = m2.id AND m2.user_id=1 AND m1.user_id=2
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec0c88/10 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec0c88/11

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Because they are different queries.
First has:

```
m2.user_id=105
```

and second has:

```
m2.user_id=1 and m1.user_id=105
```

Obviously the results are different.